# How to use pipenv on server

Tags: python, server, pipenv

I try to use `pipenv` on server

```
 task :migrate do on roles(:app) do
    execute "cd #{release_path} && /home/ubuntu/.pyenv/shims/pipenv install"
    execute "cd #{release_path} && /home/ubuntu/.pyenv/shims/pipenv run python #{release_path}/manage.py makemigrations" 
    execute "cd #{release_path} && /home/ubuntu/.pyenv/shims/pipenv run python #{release_path}/manage.py migrate"
 end
```

my `Pipfile` is here

```
[[source]]
url = "https://pypi.org/simple"
verify_ssl = true
name = "pypi"

[packages]
django = "*"
pandas = "*"
djangorestframework = "*"
markdown = "*"
django-filter = "*"
django-webpack-loader = "*"
django-crispy-forms = "*"
pymysql = "*"
beautifulsoup4 = "*"

[dev-packages]

[requires]
python_version = "3.9"
```

Then error message is here,

looks like `pipenv install` succeeded but `Django` was not installed correctly.

What is wrong?

```
DEBUG [42151ee5]    Installing dependencies from Pipfile.lock (4abb36)...
 DEBUG [42151ee5]   To activate this project's virtualenv, run pipenv shell.
Alternatively, run a command inside the virtualenv with pipenv run.
  INFO [42151ee5] Finished in 19.917 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
  INFO [35fb8a90] Running cd /var/www/html/myappp/releases/20220923122448 && /home/ubuntu/.pyenv/shims/pipenv run python /var/www/html/myapp/releases/20220923122448/manage.py makemigrations as ubuntu@panda.example.jp
 DEBUG [35fb8a90] Command: cd /var/www/html/muapp/releases/20220923122448 && /home/ubuntu/.pyenv/shims/pipenv run python /var/www/html/myapp/releases/20220923122448/manage.py makemigrations
 DEBUG [35fb8a90]   Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/share/virtualenvs/20220923122448-VTt_Iizv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/timezone.py", line 10, in <module>
    import zoneinfo
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'zoneinfo'

    raise ImportError(
ImportError: Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you forget to activate a virtual environment?
```

Comment: It is looking for the [`zoneinfo`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zoneinfo.html) module, which was introduced in Python 3.9. You appear to be running a version of Python that is older than what your installed packages require.

Comment: You are right, I updated the python version and it solved, you saved me.

Answer (score 0):

Use pipenv as a development environment.

1. Install pipenv via pip

   `pip3 install --user pipenv`
2. Run pipenv shell

   `pipenv shell`
3. Install django and packages you need

   `pipenv install django`

   `pipenv install django-crispy-forms`
4. Run your server

   `pipenv run python3 manage.py runserver`

Comment: It's better to run pipenv shell before any pipenv install X. This way the packages are only installed for the current environment and not for the global pipenv environment.

Comment: Agreed. Fixed that